# Install aria2c on Centos7

Tags: centos, aria2

I would like to install aria2c on centos7. I tried with `yum install aria/aria2/aria2c` but I receive "no package available".
What is the proper way to install aria2c on centos7?

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem? If so, please mark it as answered, otherwise, please let us know what failed. Thank you!

Comment: @JeffSchaller I solve the problem by building aria2c. I followed the steps from here( from section How to build): http://aria2.sourceforge.net/manual/en/html/README.html)

Comment: Error getting repository data for rpmforge, repository not found

Comment: If any of the existing answers solves your problem, please consider accepting it via the checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 18):

On CentOS 7.2.1511, I was able to install it through the EPEL repository:

```
$ yum install epel-release -y
$ yum install aria2 -y
```

Answer (score 2):

RPMforge repository is dead and no more maintained, the only way to install aria2 command-line download tool on CentOS or RHEL distribution from EPEL repository, as shown here - https://www.tecmint.com/aria2-multi-protocol-commandline-download-tool-for-linux/.

```
# yum install epel-release -y
# yum install aria2 -y
```

The available version is 1.18.0. So in this case you might need to compile and install the latest 1.34.0 from the source package as shown [here](https://aria2.github.io/).

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption that you've tried `yum install aria2` (instead of the literal `yum install aria/aria2/aria2c` command you listed), the [Install Aria2 (Command-line download manager) on RHEL/CentOS and Fedora linux](http://lintut.com/install-aria2-on-centos-and-fedora-linux/) page suggests the following command:

```
yum --enablerepo=rpmforge install aria2 -y
```

If you need the rpmforge repo, you can apparently get it with either:

64-bit:

```
sudo rpm -Uvh http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el6.rf.i686.rpm
```

or for 32-bit:

```
sudo rpm -Uvh http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Your assumption was correct. I tried this method but did not work: after these steps I still received the the message "no package available".

Comment: Interesting; that's what I get for not using CentOS; according to http://pkgs.org/centos-7/epel-x86_64/aria2-1.18.10-2.el7.1.x86_64.rpm.html, the EPEL repo has an "aria2" package, in case it helps.  
1. Download the latest epel-release rpm from
http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/
2.  Install epel-release rpm:
# rpm -Uvh epel-release*rpm
3. Install aria2 rpm package:
# yum install aria2

Comment: The rpmforge urls are down.  Anyone knows the valid url?

Comment: @Jeff Schaller: the step 3 does not work.  It still fails to find the aria2 package.

Answer (score 1):

Just try:

1. wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
2. rpm -ivh epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
3. yum -y install aria2